# install msi with a product code through msiexec

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I am a new to msi installations through command prompt.Can anyone show me how to install an application with product code through msiexec.
Currently I am using the command :
msiexec /i "D:\msiexec\Calculator\CalculatorInstaller\CalculatorInstaller\Express\DVD-5\DiskImages\DISK1\CalculatorInstaller.msi" ProductCode="42F48712-5C2E-41D1-83CC-2D28C91C889A" but though it's getting installed, I am not able to verify that at
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>Software>Microsoft>Wow6432nodeMicrosoft>windows>Uninstall .

Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProductCode is a private property and isn't being passed to the installer session.  I don't see why you'd need it anyways as it's in the MSI that you are installing.  You can uninstall using a ProductCode (by substituting it for the path to the MSI not by passing it as a property ) but you can't install by ProductCode (it wouldn't know how to find the MSI for that ProductCode ).

I'd log the install and read it to be sure but my hunch would be to look at the ALLUSERS property.  I'm suspecting you are installing Per-User instead of Per-Machine and that's why you don't see it in the HKLM....Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall key.